# Injective map from $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

> Show that the map $$\psi : \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}, \;\;\;\; a=(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto \sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{a_n}{10^n} $$ is injective.

In my head, and after a bit of thought, I could see that $\psi$ is indeed injective, but I'm unsure of how to explicitly show this from the definition of injectivity i.e. $\forall a,b \in \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N},\;f(a)=f(b) \implies a=b $.

Any help would be welcomed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have that

\begin{align}
f(a)=f(b)\iff f(a)-f(b)=0
&\iff \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n-b_n}{10^n}=0\\
&\iff \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n-b_n+1}{10^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10^n}
\end{align}

With $d_n=a_n-b_n+1$, we have that $d_n\in \{0,1,2\}$, so the LHS is the number with decimal representation $0.d_1d_2d_3\dots$ while the RHS is the number $0.111\dots$

It follows that equivality holds if and only if $d_n=1$ for all $n\geq 1$. This implies $a_n=b_n$ for all $n\geq 1$, that is, $a=b$ (as sequences).

---

This should be expected, since the problem that usually arises with a real number having multiple decimal representations happens only when we have a tail of $9$s, which clearly cannot happen for $f$.

Comment: To identify coefficients, we somehow need $a_n-b_n\in\{0,..,9\}$ but here it can be $-1$. I think we can trick it by comparing $f(a)-f(b)+\frac 13=\frac 13$ then we can compare $2\le 3+a_n-bn\le 4$ and $3$ for all $n$.

Comment: @zwim If you're not quite convinced, just add $0.1111\dots$ to both sides, so that the possible digits for the LHS are $0,1$ or $2$, while the RHS has only $1$s.

Comment: But then why not identify directly $a_n$ and $b_n$ ? The subtraction only brings issues.

Comment: @zwim I'm not quite sure. This seems obvious enough, but clearly the question implies some sort of difficulty with the idea.

Comment: So to prove $\psi$ is injective, you use that $\psi(a_n-b_n+\frac 19)=\psi(\frac 19)\implies a_n-b_n+\frac 19=\frac 19$ thanks to injectivity...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Decimal expansions of real numbers are (almost) unique, and the caveat leading to my inclusion of the word "almost" doesn't arise here.